# Include C file which is located in the same folder as the main c file

Tags: c, preprocessor-directive

I have a folder which contains 3 files:

- main.c
- file1.c
- file2.c

The idea is to compile only one file basing on a symbol if it's defined or not.

in main.c, I added the following lines:

```
#ifdef MY_SYMBOL
 #include "file1.c"
#else
 #include "file2.c"
#endif
```

The problem that I found is that when **MY_SYMBOL** is defined, **file1.c** is compiled twice because in the makefile it's mentionned to compile all source files inside each folder.

The limitation is that I shouldn't modify the makefile! So, to avoid that I modified the extension of **file1.c** and **file2.c** to **file1.h** and **file2.h** respectively, by keeping their content (definition of all private functions), and I updated the content of main.c as following:

```
#ifdef MY_SYMBOL
 #include "file1.h"
#else
 #include "file2.h"
#endif
```

Taking into account the above limitation, is the last proposal the best way ?

Note that **file1.c** and **file2.c** contain the same functions but with different implementation.

Comment: Generally you shouldn't include source modules in other source modules, that's what headers are for, you could use the pre-processor in your make file to optionally compile the source file.

Comment: @SPlatten The limitation is that I shouldn't modify the makefile.

Comment: Then you have to take a hit on the file size as both source modules will be compiled and linked in with the exec.  The only option for you is to ensure that everything in the source modules is static or has different names then use the headers to specify different names for each.

Comment: by keeping the first or 2nd version of main.c?

Comment: You will have to have separate headers as you have in the second version then use different prototypes in the headers to reference each source module.  You could use a prefix for each and use the pre-processor definition as the function prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Among others, C programers usually do not expect one of the following:

1. .h-files that contain function implementations or variable definitions
2. .c-files that get included.

So I'd say with both ways you will somehow "surprise" others.

If you must not alter the `makefile` (BTW: why?), you could encapsulate the implementation variants in your `.c`-files within preprocessor-directives:

```
// file1.c  (OR: file_mysym_implementation.c):
#ifdef MY_SYMBOL
   // code goes here
#endif

// file2.c  (OR: file_non_mysym_implementation.c):
#ifndef MY_SYMBOL
   // code goes here
#endif
```

Additionally, you will need *one* header file which declares all the functions exposed by the respective implementation.